# Firebase version of latest Salesforce Service SDK is outdated

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, sdk, snap-ins, salesforce-sdk-android

We have noticed that latest Service SDK https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-Android/releases/tag/224.0.0 seems to still be using Firbase 17.3.0.

Can anyone know when the Service SDK team will be updating their FireBase version to 20.1.0 or later ?

Comment: MobileSDK analytics is crashing because it's incompatible with later version of okhttp (unclear why these crashes are not just caught in the error handler) but seems to be addressed here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/1955
Unfortunately this is using Firebase 20.0.1 which is as above different from ServiceSDK.
Can someone please address this as soon as possible.